# Create generic SQL INSERT statement from datatable with looping

Tags: c#, sql, loops

I'm trying to create a generic method of taking a datatable and creating a SQL INSERT statement from its contents.

I've spent the better part of a couple of days researching this on StackOverflow.

I just need some help with the looping section code--it doesn't give the desired results and I've reached the limit of my coding skills.

I don't need BulkCopy solutions or database specific ones.  I just need the INSERT string.  I don't care about SQL injections or anything else.  This is an internal legacy app that needs to have a few repetitive/manual processes automated.

I have written an example console program to demonstrate.  The size of the datatable isn't really a factor form me.  It is never over 60 rows and has 6 columns:

The datatable should look like:

```
ID  Group   X       Y     Z
1   A       100     200   400
2   B       200     400   800
3   C       300     600   1200
4   D       400     800   1600
5   E       500     1000  2000
```

The example console app is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace crSQLInsert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Group");
            dt.Columns.Add("X");
            dt.Columns.Add("Y");
            dt.Columns.Add("Z");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                char cLtr = Convert.ToChar(i+65);
                double colVal = ((i + 1) * 100) ;
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ID"] = 1 + i;
                dr["Group"] = cLtr;
                dr["X"] = colVal ;
                dr["Y"] = colVal * 2;
                dr["Z"] = colVal * 4;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            createSQL(dt);
        }


        public static void createSQL(DataTable dtSQL)
        {
            // Create generic SQL query to add datatable contents to my_table
            string sSQL = "";
            sSQL += "INSERT INTO my_table (ID, Group, X, Y, Z) VALUES (";

            for (int i = 0; i < dtSQL.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < dtSQL.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    sSQL += dtSQL.Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim();
                    if (j != dtSQL.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        sSQL += "','";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sSQL += "')";
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sSQL);
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting SQL string *should be* like below:

(I've formatted it so that it's easier to read--the actual string doesn't necessarily need the \r\n as it will end up as a string in an ODBCCommand().

```
INSERT INTO my_table (ID, Group, X, Y, Z) 
 VALUES (1','A','100','200','400'),
        (2','B','200','400','800'),
        (3','C','300','600','1200'),
        (4','D','400','800','1600'),
        (5','E','500','1000','2000');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Jeremy_Miller you are only creating the opening parenthesis once, before you start your outer loop, I would move that inside the beginning of your outer loop `sSQL += ("` and also, as ARC pointed out, you are missing the first `'` before each set's  first  value, so you'd need to account for that as well. Since it's an ID column, make sure it's not an auto-incremented identity column, as you can leave it out of your insert. Also, if it's a primary key, how do you know you won't be trying to insert a value that exists already?

Comment: If you have an in memory DataTable and you are using MS SQL Server then I would recommend you use a TBV instead especially if the number of records can be large in number. You would need to create a type in Sql Server and then you could use an INSERT INTO SELECT instead of INSERT INTO VALUES which would be much more efficient and performant.

Comment: if you choose to build your own query anyways using INSERT INTO VALUES then you should be building a parameterized query instead of concatenating the values. This is more secure (no chance of sql injection) and you do not have to worry about syntax errors due to not escaping values in strings. It can also be more performant when compared to string concatenation (not as performant as the TBV though).

Comment: Which dbms are you using?